# Keymaps added with python don't work in addon `__init__.py`

Tags: python, add-on, keymap

For the life of me I can't figure out why this is happening.

I have an addon I wrote, nothing terribly complicated, just some pie menus and custom operators. I store the kwargs for the keymaps in a dictionary that I loop through on register and use to create the keymap and keymap items.

For some reason the keymaps are not created when run from the `__init__` file in my addon.

I can take the create_keymaps function and the keymap_settings dict and run it in the Blender text editor and it creates the keymaps no problem. The error only occurs when I try to create it on script load in the `__init__`.

I have tried every possible configuration in the `__init__.py`, putting the keymap setup into it's own function, putting it before/after the register function, putting it in the body of the `__init__` file, putting it in the `if __name__ == "__main__"`: section, just every stupid idea in the book.

To me it seems like it might be getting run too early or something, I can't really tell, because other than this the addon works fine, everything loads and runs with no Traceback, so it's hard to tell exactly where it's going wrong.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/jmobley0429/my_pie_menus/blob/master/__init__.py) for the `__init__.py` file in it's entirety.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I guess I figured it out, I was accidentally using a new reference to the wm.addon_keyconfig each loop rather than at the start of the register_keymaps function.

```
def register_keymaps():
    # this line needs to go up here
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager

    for setting in KMS:
        args = list(dict(sorted(setting.items())).values())
        alt, class_name, ctrl, letter, name, region_type, shift, space_type = args

        # I had it right here:
        # wm = bpy.context.window_manager

        kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name=name, space_type=space_type, region_type=region_type)
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', letter, 'PRESS', shift=shift, ctrl=ctrl, alt=alt)
        kmi.properties.name = class_name
        kmi.active = True

        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```